# Laravel Validation not between in range of numbers (opposide of between rule)

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to restrict user to **not** using some numbers in input, For example 1 to 14, I did it in dirty way:

```php
'role' => 'required|not_in:'.implode(',',range(1,14)),
```

Is there any better and laravel way to do this beside of creating custom rule ?

Note: `required|digits_between:1,14` Not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say that's a dirty way, however I would also consider using the [Greater Than](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-gt) rule if I know that 1-14 are not allowed:

```
'role' => 'required|gt:14',
```

-- EDIT

as @lagbox suggested, adding the [integer](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-integer) rule is good too it ensures that the input data is an integer

```
'role' => 'required|integer|gt:14',
```

Comment: might want to add the `integer` rule to ensure validation of a numeric value and not a string's length?